# Is it possible to plot multi columns stacked bar graph?

Tags: ipad, core-plot

I want to plot a two columns stacked bar graph, the data looks like as below, is it possible?
10/09 0.00% -36.94% 528.2502 0.0000
   0.0000 333.0924 0.0000 16.1814 178.9764

10/08 0.00% -40.19% 527.7252 0.0000
   3.4708 310.5550 1.6321 0.0000 212.0673

10/07 0.00% -38.09% 527.4240 0.0000
   0.0000 326.5490 0.0000 8.5167 192.3583

10/06 0.00% -40.41% 527.4240 0.0000
   2.9404 306.9600 4.3696 0.0000 213.1540
![alt text][1]

http://www.geocities.jp/mikezang/iPad/graph.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to getting a two-column bar chart, it is very easy. You simply need to add two different CPBarPlot to your graph. Then, when implementing CPBarPlotDataSource methods, you need to return the correct values, depending on the plot that is passed as an argument.

Unfortunately, Core-Plot does not support stacked bar chart at the moment. See post below:
http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/a65885bf16aa5a5e/b3b82880d13482f2?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=stack#b3b82880d13482f2